# Change apache ssl configuration to nginx config

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, security, ssl, migration

I want to ask your help to change my apache ssl config to nginx style. Actually i have tried it a googled but

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key/netlime_tk.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.cer
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.cer
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!SSLv2:!SSLv3
```

Actually i have done this but in ssl_protools are missing the exclude of versions, also everytime i have done "connected" chain with certificates, the ssl testing websites reported that these are wrong so i dont really want to join certificates together.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!SSLv2:!SSLv3;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key/netlime_tk.key;
#ssl_certificate_chain /etc/nginx/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.cer;
#ssl_ca_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.cer;
```

Thank you :-* if you can give some technical explanation witch will teach me something then please do it.

### Edit

Thank for all for help and time the final config for "Grade A" on ssllabs is

```
# SSL Configuration
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.crt.bundle;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key/netlime_tk.key;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384.....very long string'
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /root/dhparams.pem;
```

Comment: Nginx needs the primary and intermediate certificates in a bundled cert file. What I do is concatenate the SSL Cert and the issuer's certs into a bundle file and load that in the `ssl_cetificate` line.  So a `cat www_netlime_tk.crt www_netlime_tk.cer > www_netlime_tk.crt.bundle` and use the .bundle file as the `ssl_certificate` setting. There's a good explanation and guide here: [https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm]

Comment: Thankyou, and what about other configs? when i add ssl_protocols the "all" is nvalid param, the -SSLv2 is invalid, -SSLv3 is invalid,...

Comment: `-SSLv2` and -`SSLv3` remove SSL version 2 & 3 so that mean it allow TLS like your nginx configuration already does `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;` .Anyway you can test your SSL level here : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Comment: Yes I always use ssllabs, a great thanks letting me know that adding tls and not mentioning SSLvXY will do de exclude. Now I have got "Grade A" looks sweat :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    server_name  yourhostname;    #rename your hostname
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/cert/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/cert/server.key;
    ssl_buffer_size 4K;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m; ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    location ~ ^(?<script_name>.+?\.php)(?<path_info>/.*)?$ {
            try_files $script_name = 404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;         #for https
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, because problem was solved, i cannot accept your answer. But it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

1. To create a join together *.crt and *.cer files using cat command (thanks to user Gmck)
2. Specify only protocols that are allowed in my case TLS v1 v1.1 and v1.2 (thanks to user Froggiz)
3. Add more specific ciphers (thanks to ssllabs website)
4. add dhparams for more secure connection (thanks to ssllabs website)

Final SSL config

```
# SSL Configuration
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crt/www_netlime_tk.crt.bundle;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key/netlime_tk.key;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH.....very long string (google for full string)';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /root/dhparams.pem;
```